# Android - Function execute listener

Tags: android, function, events, listener, handler

Hey i don't know if that's the right way to do it but if it is how can i do it...

I have one abstact class with AsyncTask

```
public abstract class A{
  A(){
    new Task().execute();
  }

  public abstract void postAction();

  private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
      //smth
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
       postAction();
    }
  }
}
```

After that i have class that extends A class and overrides it's `postAction()` method:

```
public class B extends A{
   B(){
      //smth
   }

   postAction(){
     //some action
   }
}
```

In my activity i have instance of `B` and i want to perform action when postAction is called... so i want function listener if possible and how can i do it

```
class C extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstance);
      //somethingggg happeiningggg
   }

   MyListener listener = new MyListener(){
       onPostActionCalled()
       {
         //start another activity or smt :D
       }
   };
}
```

So i have class for json response(`class A`) and `class B` that extends it and overrides it's post method so i can do what i want for specific situation(expect different data or smth else nvm)

In my activity i want to perform action when `class B`'s post method is called

I don't know if i need to do listener or handler idk at all....

Comment: Why all the difficulties with extending classes and having inner Asynctasks? Simply create a custom listener (interface), create a stand-alone AsyncTask which will take that listener as parameter and call it's functions and in your Activity implement the interface and call the AsyncTask with 'this'.

Comment: Because... I want it like that :D I mean my A class is abstract with AsyncTask... I use my A class for server communicattor... my application will make like 20 different requests to the server. So i don't want to make 20 different AsyncTasks... I use B class to handle the response( i will have 20 classes like B class that will override `postAction()` method and will have some different methods inside B: write in file, cash data, do the moneky :D and etc)... And my C class is my activity... nvm i made interface and added it to A & B constructors :)

Comment: If you want to use this for networking, you shouldn't anyhow ;) Networking should be in a service for a number of good reasons. Check out the library RoboSpice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan is right, why complicate things?

See this real simple example of threading:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    new MyTask(new TaskListener() {

        @Override
        public void finished(boolean result) {
            // back on main thread after task finishes

        }
    }).execute();
}

private interface TaskListener{
    void finished(boolean result);      
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Boolean>{

    private TaskListener mListener; 


    public MyTask(TaskListener mListener) {
        super();
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // long running background operation
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mListener.finished(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Let's say... I made it because of your post, but your post is not exactly what i wanted... It can be made better then ur example but i'll mark as answer ;) :D I added interface in my `A class` it's called PostActionListener i added as an argument of the A and B classes constructor in my AsyncTask constructor i added PostActionListener argument and field to AsyncTask class that is PostActionListener `mListnr = null` in my constructor i give value of mListnr and in post i check if it's not null i start it's method... so it's good now